Donorbox and Salesforce Integration
I am writing to request guidance on exporting data from DonorBox to Salesforce Sandbox.
I found the source of the errors are "With a lot of triggers and classes within NPSP, you can 'turn off' or bypass within the NPSP settings app or within setup > custom meta data. I would advise to see if you have any TDTM settings currently running, then take a look and see if you can control it at all first. You can then deactivate the TDTM restriction. This could look something like ADDR_Contact_TDTM for example."
I tried to export some records from Donorbox to Salesforce while turning off the triggers ADDR_Account_TDTM, ADDR_Contact_TDTM, and ADDR_Addresses_TDTM, but the export failed again. I'm not sure why this is happening.
I would appreciate your help in resolving them.
I have encountered several errors while exporting data from Donorbox to Salesforce, which I have listed below.
There were 414 donations/plans/tickets that failed to export or exported with missing fields.
Please visit the Export Failures Logs to view the full list. There could be permission or data compatibility issues in Salesforce.
After you fixed these issues in Salesforce, use the "Re-export" button on that page to try again.
Failed Donation/Plan Exports:
Error message 1:

CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY: npsp.TDTM_Contact: execution of
AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First
exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY,
npsp.TDTM_Address: execution of AfterInsert caused by:
System.TypeException: Cannot have more than 10 chunks in a single
operation. Please rearrange the data to reduce chunking. (System
Code): [] (System Code) RESPONSE: [{"message":"npsp.TDTM_Contact:
execution of AfterUpdate\n\ncaused by: System.DmlException: Insert
failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, npsp.TDTM_Address: execution of
AfterInsert\n\ncaused by: System.TypeException: Cannot have more than
10 chunks in a single operation. Please rearrange the data to reduce
chunking.\n\n(System Code): []\n\n(System
Code)","errorCode":"CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY","fields":[]}]

Error message 2:

CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY: npsp.TDTM_Contact: execution of
AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First
exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY,
npsp.TDTM_Address: execution of AfterInsert caused by:
System.TypeException: Cannot have more than 10 chunks in a single
operation. Please rearrange the data to reduce chunking. (System
Code): [] (System Code) RESPONSE: [{"message":"npsp.TDTM_Contact:
execution of AfterUpdate\n\ncaused by: System.DmlException: Insert
failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, npsp.TDTM_Address: execution of
AfterInsert\n\ncaused by: System.TypeException: Cannot have more than
10 chunks in a single operation. Please rearrange the data to reduce
chunking.\n\n(System Code): []\n\n(System
Code)","errorCode":"CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY","fields":[]}]

